# Application of Cauchy's integral theorem or Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Here a beginner in complex variable analysis. They ask me to evaluate the following integral using the Cauchy integral formula or the Cauchy integral theorem

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint \frac{(\cos z+\operatorname{sen} z)}{\left(z^{2}+25\right)(z+1)} d z \quad \text { about }  \frac{x^{2}}{9}+\frac{y^{2}}{16}=1$$

I do not understand very well how to use it and it would be very helpful if you could recommend bibliography

Comment: I'm sorry to ask such a silly question... What does $\text{sen} z$ means? Wolfram alpha said it is $\sin z$, but when I saw it first, I thought it can be typo of $\sec z$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Cauchy integral formula:

**Theorem.** Let $f$ analytic everywhere within and on a simple closed contour $C$, taken in the positive sense. if $z_{0}$ is any ponint interior to $C$, then

$$ f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}} dz$$

The reference is Churchill et. al. *Complex variables and applications*.

In your case

$$ C= \left\{z = x+iy\in \mathbb{C} \big|  \frac{x^{2}}{9}+\frac{y^{2}}{16}=1 \right\}$$

Note that $C$ in an ellipse in the complex plane with vertex at $x= \pm 3$ and covertex at $y=\pm 4$

The integrand $\displaystyle \frac{(\cos z+\operatorname{sen} z)}{\left(z^{2}+25\right)(z+1)}$ has three singularities:

$$ z = \pm i5 \Longrightarrow y = \pm 5 $$

and

$$ z = -1 \Longrightarrow x = -1$$

So, the singularities at $y=\pm i5$ are out of the covertex range, the only singularity inside $C$ is $z=-1$

Then, if you define

$$f(z) = \frac{(\cos z+\operatorname{sen} z)}{\left(z^{2}+25\right)}$$

the function $f$ is analytic within and on the contour $C$, the ellipse. If you put $z_{0} = -1$ you have all the ingredients to apply the theorem.

Comment: Thanks! but when i replace $z_{0} = -1$, i don't get complex value, or i think i'm wrong. The numerator, even if I express it with exponentials, does not look good

Comment: Maybe if we put in this form is more clear:  $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \underbrace{\frac{\cos z+\sin z}{\left(z^{2}+25\right)}}_{f(z) \textrm{analytic whithin and on C}}  \frac{1}{(z-\underbrace{(-1)}_{z_{0}})} d z$$